# В терминале не выводится строка перед длительной операцией

Tags: terminal, c++, sublime-text

Работаю в Ubuntu 14.04 x86, Sublime Text 2 + терминал

Странность высветилась во время вывода строки перед длительной операцией. Я использовал выделение большого кол-ва памяти:

```
MyType* type;
long int MyNumber = 3000000;

cout << "Initialization... ";
MyType* type = new MyType[MyNumber];
cout << "Done! << endl;
```

По всей логике вывод терминала должен быть следующим:

```
Initialization...*пауза* Done!
```

Но по какой-то причине пауза проходит вначале, а две строки выводятся одновременно.

```
*пауза* Initialization... Done!
```

После добавления к выводу первой строки команды `endl` первая надпись срабатывает так, как нужно.

```
Initialization...
*пауза*
Done!
```

Что за особенность работы терминала такая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не особенность терминала, а свойство всех буферизированных потоков вывода. Пока не будет вызван метод `flush()`, или в поток не попадёт `\n` - данные из буфера не будут переданы на устройство.

Comment: @klopp: Насколько я понимаю, `\n` не производит flush, а вот `std::endl` производит.

Comment: А, что-то уже забывать стал - cout, он line buffered или fully buffered?

Comment: @VladD, нет. По `\n` реально вывод проводится.

     cout << "xaxa  \n ...";
     sleep(2);
     cout << "xoxo\n";

выводит с задержкой перед ...хохо

    avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
    xaxa  
     ...xoxo
    avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ 

(тут ее просто не видно)

Comment: @avp: Это у вас потому, что stdout в вашем случае line-buffered.

<http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl>:

> **`std::endl`**  
> Inserts a newline character into the output sequence os and flushes it as if by calling `os.put(os.widen('\n'))` followed by `os.flush()`.
> 
> ...
>
> In many implementations, standard output is line-buffered, and writing `'\n'` causes a flush anyway, unless `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false)` was executed.

Comment: @klopp: зависит от имплементации, я бы на конкретный тип буферизации не забивался.

Comment: @VladD, вот даже как...

std::endl оказывается как `fflush()` работает (т.е. не только с character потоком будет вывод выталкивать).

Вот поэтому (слишком много всяких тонкостей, не говоря о более фундаментальных недостатках) я тоже  не советую писать что-нибудь более-менее  серьезное на [крестах](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus).

Comment: @avp: Угу. У них не лучшие абстракции, к сожалению.

Comment: Что-ж, спасибо за ответы, надо прочесть на досуге